# Using stokes theorem to calculate line integral (what am I doing wrong?)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\Sigma$ be the triangle with corners $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. Calculate the line integral $$\int_\Sigma (x+y^2)dx+(y+z^2)dy+(z+x^2)dz, $$ where the contour has a positive orientation seen from the point $(1,1,1)$. Use the stokes theorem.

So the surface of the triangle can be parametrized by $r(s,t)=(s,t,1-s-t)$ where $0\leq t\leq 1-s$ and $0\leq s\leq 1$.

And if $F(x,y,z)=(x+y^2,y+z^2,z+x^2)$ then $\text{curl }F=(-2z,-2x,-2y)$ since $R_y=0$, $Q_z=2z$, $P_z=0$, $R_x=2x$, $Q_x=0$, $P_y=2y$.

Also from $r_s=(1,0,-1)$ and $r_t=(0,1,-1)$ we have $r_s\times r_t=(1,1,1)$.

So by stokes theorem the line integral is given by $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-s}\text{curl }F(r(s,t))\cdot(r_s\times r_t)dtds=-2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-s}(1-t-s+s+t)dtds=-1/3.$$

The right answer is $-1$.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-s}1dtds$ is the area of the right triangle of vertices $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$, which is $\frac{1\cdot 1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^{1-s}(1-t-s+s+t)\,dt\,ds &= \int_0^1\int_0^{1-s}\,dt\,ds \\
&= \int_0^1(1-s)\,ds \\
&= s-\frac{s^2}{2}\Large|_0^1 \\
&= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: guess I shouldn't trust symbolab